# Issue using .htaccess on a linux server

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, webserver

So I have a site where once there was a wiki structure in php

Now I have a completely clean site now started up from scratch (so no hidden .htaccess files etc. or other installed components) but need to redirect incoming url requests for the old site to a new html structure

I imagined I could do it using an .htaccess file

I have tried a variation of syntax in the .htaccess file for example:

```
<IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectPermanent 3dprintfo.com/doku.php?id=3dproject2 http://3dprintfo.com/3dproject2.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c/>
<IfModule>
```

And for example:

```
RedirectPermanent 301 3dprintfo.com/doku.php?id=3dproject2 http://3dprintfo.com/3dproject2.html

RedirectPermanent http://3dprintfo.com/doku.php?id=3dproject2 http://3dprintfo.com/3dproject2.html
```

However nothing works I keep getting:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have tried with and without http/301 etc.

Can anyone try to show me an example with multiple url redirects that I can try to implement using my above url names...

Comment: Are there two different domains; old and new? In your first example you appear to be trying to redirect from `3dprintfo.com` to `printfo.com`? If so, where do these domains point to? (Do they both point to the same vHost?) It looks like the value of the `id` URL parameter should map to the URL-path + `.html`? Is this a physical file? Is it always a file in the document root? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Sorry thats just me who made a typo

Comment: But a very valid point :)

Comment: I had been at it most of the late afternoon/evening

Comment: Yes the .html is a physical file in root - I could put it in a subdir if that would make a difference... probably should to keep things tidy.

Comment: As for the other questions - No the .htaccess at this point is pristine - Nothing but the redirects at this time. As for the .php the structure is identical for all of them.

Comment: In general I would suggest that you should implement such rule in the actual http server's host configuration and _not_ in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an example of a working redirection, as far as I understand your question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?3dprintfo\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=3dproject2$
RewriteRule ^/?doku\.php$ /3dproject2.html [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Of course it is possible to implement more general rules, so that you won't need a catalog of rules for each and every "old page". But that obviously depends on your link structure used previously.

In general I would suggest that you should implement such rule in the actual http server's host configuration and not in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). But above rule is written such that it works in *both* locations.

The first `RewriteCond` might not be required, depends on what else is configured inside your http server.

---

UPDATE:

For what you ask in your first comment to this question I'd suggest something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?3dprintfo\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?doku\.php$ /%1.html [R=301,QSD,L]
```

This variant additionally checks if a file named for example `3dproject2.html` actually exists before rewriting to it.

Comment: Since I have purposely called the html files the same as the ID for example "3dproject2" could I replace: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=3dproject2$ - With RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=*$ and replace RewriteRule ^/?doku\.php$ /3dproject2.html [R=301,QSD,L] with RewriteRule ^/?doku\.php$ /*.html [R=301,QSD,L] .... ? I will have to try that out

Comment: Nope, that is not how things work. I added an "UPDATE" to the answer for what you ask in your comment. And I really recommend to you to start reading a bit about how the tools you want to use actually work. I am sure you will easily solve such tasks yourself then. Start here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you again and thanks for the direct reference to the Apache site, was getting served up a million different pages - Information overload :) Have a fantastic day!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. We all learn. You will see that the documentation of the apache http server and all of its modules is of excellent quality.